# How do i decrypt my mysql password

Tags: mysql, sql, passwords, encryption

I am currently trying to figure out my old password.

I was hosting the website personally until we switched and another staff member took over.

Anyway. How would i go about decrypting my password?

password - 62d8937f554cf8ebe29940bf577eb22b
salt - 9D4kWKQW

Comment: It should be easier to reset the password.

Comment: It's on another host and i don't have access to the email.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot decrypt password, at least not easily.

If you have root shell access to the server in question, you can [follow standard instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html) to assign new password.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a MySQL password.

MySQL password hashes are 40 hex characters long (at least MySQL 4.1 and later).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html

That's 32 characters, so it's probably an MD5 hash.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know what algorithm is to create the password you could create a rainbow-table of the results with the salt until you find a match.

Can take some time though.

Comment: I sadly do not know the algorithm.